# C# MVC Datepicker Behave Differently in IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, iis-8

I had a C# MVC5 web application with a DatePicker created in VS2017 as shown below. The Datepicker been set to dd/mm/yy and it's working properly in VS2017 debugging. But when I deployed it to IIS, the control date format was changed to mm/dd/yy and causing invalid date for the control. The datepicker function was added into a shared _LayoutView.cshtml. Any advice is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
    $(function () {
        $(".date-picker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
    });   

     <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Check your server's regional settings, also with culture settings in web.config file. If your server still uses `mm/dd/yy` format, you need to change it into `dd/mm/yy` format.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does solve my problem. I just change the setting in IIS according to my region. https://community.ivanti.com/docs/DOC-22918